# Extracting using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract the year from this column :

[image]

what I know is I split it by `,` into a list using

```
df['yearcorrect'] = df['released'].astype(str).str.split(',')
```

I can not go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"t":["te,1723(hd k)","683, 7939(jod ls)"]})

df["year"]=df.t.str.split(r"[,(]",expand=True)[1]

print(df)
"""
                   t   year
0      te,1723(hd k)   1723
1  683, 7939(jod ls)   7939
"""
```

`pandas.Series.str.split` supports regular expression so, we are using this to split text. We are splitting text into 3 part before `comma` and year and after `(` and taking that year column only by using `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
dates = df["released"].to_list()
date_list = list()

for each_date in dates:
    temp_date = each_date.split(",")[1]
    year = temp_date.split("(")[0]
    year = year.strip()
    # this is where you can extract the year
    # print(year)
    date_list.append(year)

df["year"] = date_list
```

You can definitely reduce the lines of code by aggregating the functions but for the sake of simplicity I have broken them down in steps. Hope this helps. Please feel free to reach out if the issue still persists.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68719932/12446721), I believe your answer is same as mine and mine better. :)

Comment: Does this solved OPs problem completely? Isn't OP asking to add new column, is OP asking to print the year?

Comment: That is correct @Xitiz. To completely solve the problem, the print statement should be replaced by, year_list.append(year) # where year_list is the list of all years. Outside the for loop, a simple df["year"] = year_list would include this year data in the existing dataframe.

Comment: Yeah! I believe you can do that. In that way question will be completely solved.

Comment: lol I just saw you changed your first comment :D

Comment: :P I found that lately!

Comment: lol..lets leave it up to the person who asked it :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to get the year number, which is usually 4 digits.
but findall() will return years like this: `[1998]`,`[2001]`. You can apply the lambda function to unsqueeze your data.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"t":["te,1723(hd k)","683, 7939(jod ls)"]})
df["year"]= df["t"].str.findall("\d{4}").apply(lambda x:  x[0])
```

[image]